# Shift+Space key combination blocked in KDE Neon

Tags: keyboard, plasma, kde-neon

I installed KDE Neon recently, and really liking it, but I have this pet peeve that I can't type a space while the shift key is pressed down (I type in all-caps sometimes while writing code).  Used to work fine in Ubuntu-MATE, but not in Neon.

It's a mechanical keyboard, and I've verified that I can press both keys when running on my Windows partition, so I know it's not a hardware issue.

Anyone know what configuration options I might need to change in Plasma to make this key combination work again?